# How to update old version of my app to TWA

Tags: android, twa

I've created a TWA for my service but when I try to install it on an android that already have an old version of our app (written in java) it can't be installed. Is there something I'm missing? How do our users suppose to update their old version of our app?

I have updated the versions both for code and name.

I have followed this link https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

Answer (score 0):

For updating App, we need to change `versionCode` in `app.gradle` like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1 //change this to 2
        versionName "1.0" // also change this to something like "1.1"
    }
}
```

So your updated `app.gradle` will be something like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2 //changed it from 1 to 2
        versionName "1.1" //changed it from 1.0 to 1.1
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I have changed the version of both versoinCode and versionName I jump from 10 to 20 for code and 1.4 to 2.0 for name. I guess it wouldn't be a problem. would  be?

Comment: No it is not a problem, but you have to keep on increasing, next time you can set something like `30` or `40`. jumping this many versions is not recommended but you can do it

Comment: beside the version what should I do? I got the problem and it's not clear what it is.

Comment: Please tell me full form of `TWA` (is this your app name?) and also update your question with `logs`

Comment: which logs? the build and testing on emulator is ok just the installation of the `.apk` on my phone is a problem. when I remove the old version it will be installed

Comment: TWA means Trusted Web Activities

Comment: @SaeedAmin for updating app all you need to do is follow my answer, there must be something else missing or some other errors

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens on an emulator when you try to install a release version alongside the debug version on the same emulator. Make sure that you're installing the release version of your TWA if the old Java app is a release version too.

Android Studio installs a debug version every time you debug on the emulator. To install the release version, first generate a signed apk (more info here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) and once generated, use the following command on your terminal:

```
adb install app-release.apk
```

Make sure that you provide the full path to the release version of your signed apk file after the "adb install" command.